# java agent - Instrument selected files (exclude all inbuilt java classes and methods)

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I am writing my first java agent. I am trying to instrument a project that I picked from git repo (not developed by me).

I have written my Agent class with the premain method and implement some logging ( logs the number of lines executed using the ASM bytecode manipulation framework)

However, I see that even the inbuilt java function calls/ classes are getting instrumented which is incorrect. I only want the files in my project to be instrumented. To achieve this, I added a filter shown below -

```
  public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

    System.out.println("Premain called");

    inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
      public byte[] transform(ClassLoader classLoader, 
                              String className,
                              Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
                              ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, 
                              byte[] bytes)throws IllegalClassFormatException {


        // ASM Code
        if(className.startsWith("org/mytestpackage/")){
          ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(bytes);
          ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(reader, 0);
          ClassTransformVisitor visitor = new ClassTransformVisitor(writer);
          reader.accept(visitor, 0);
          return writer.toByteArray();
        } 

        return null;

      }
    });

  }
```

After I added this filter, the premain is being called but I am getting some exception

```
initializationError(org.mytestpackage.TestAllPackages)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/mytestpackage/TestAllPackages, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Stack size too large
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
```

Before I added this filter ( if condition based on the className), I was able to see my logic work for inbuilt java classes and methods. If fails after adding the filter.

Appreciate any help, TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ClassTransformVisitor` seems to break the code of your transformed case. In your particular case, it seems to not adjust the stack size of methods in your class `org.mytestpackage.TestAllPackages`.

The verifier error `Stack size too large` indicates that you push more values to a method's operand stack than what you specified as slots for this stack. You can ask ASM to fix this for you by specifying `new ClassWriter(reader, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS)`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. They way I created the classwriter seemed to be causing the problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you are not calculating the max sizes yourself, I’d guess that you are not creating stackmap frames either. So you should rather use `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES` to calculate both, in case the class versions are 50 or higher.